# Concurrent Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to implement concurrent Dictionary because .Net does not contain concurrent implementation for collections(Since .NET4 will be contains). Can I use for it "Power Threading Library" from Jeffrey Richter  or present implemented variants or any advice for implemented?
Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to view the source code of the concurrent implementation of .NET 4.0 RC and copy it to your own code. This way you will have the least problems when migrating to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Unless it uses any new features that are not available in dotNET 3.5. And there could be copyright issues here.

Comment: I would discourage you to reverse-engineering the 4.0 Fx..  This is a solvable/solved problem for which there are known/tested solutions.  You can use the 4.0 Fx for inspiration, but otherwise I don't think this is sound advice.

Comment: It looks like this is the .NET v4 impl refactored: http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Frameworks/PLINQO/Source/CodeSmith.Data/Collections/ConcurrentDictionary.cs?r=1991

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a thread-safe wrapper for the normal Dictionary class that uses Interlocked to protect the internal dictionary. Interlocked is by far the fastest locking mechanism available and will give much better performance than ReaderWriterLockSlim, Monitor or any of the other available locks.

The code was used to implement a [Cache](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/32749c4dd310#Fasterflect/Fasterflect/Caching/Cache.cs) class for [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com), which is a library to speed up reflection. As such we tried a number of different approaches in order to find the fastest possible solution. Interestingly, the new concurrent collections in .NET 4 are noticeably faster than my implementation, although both are pretty darn fast compared to solutions using a less performance locking mechanism. The implementation for .NET 3.5 is located inside a conditional region in the bottom half of the file.

Comment: I took a look at your Fasterflect home page and saw your Person class example having that instance count inside the class. Wouldn't that open you to concurrency issues as there is no locking on it? I recently did some verification that C# ++/-- operators are not atomic and I didn't see any information that contradicted my understanding.

Comment: The Person class is just a sample class used to show how Fasterflect can be used. It is not meant to be thread safe. The code I was referring to above is the Cache class located in the main Fasterflect project. Click the Cache link above to go directly to the source browser on CodePlex.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a concurrent dictionary myself (prior to .NET 4.0's `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace); there's not much to it. You basically just want to make sure certain methods are not getting called at the same time, e.g., `Contains` and `Remove` or something like that.

What I did was to use a `ReaderWriterLock` (in .NET 3.5 and above, you could go with `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) and call `AcquireReaderLock` for all "read" operations (like `this[TKey]`, `ContainsKey`, etc.) and `AcquireWriterLock` for all "write" operations (like `this[TKey] = value`, `Add`, `Remove`, etc.). Be sure to wrap any calls of this sort in a `try`/`finally` block, releasing the lock in the `finally`.

It's also a good idea to modify the behavior of `GetEnumerator` slightly: rather than enumerate over the existing collection, make a copy of it and allow enumeration over that. Otherwise you'll face potential deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation that uses sane locking (though [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) would likely be faster):
http://www.tech.windowsapplication1.com/content/the-synchronized-dictionarytkey-tvalue

Essentially, just create a Dictionary wrapper/decorator and synchronize access to any read/write actions.

When you switch to .Net 4.0, just replace all of your overloads with delegated calls to the underlying ConcurrentDictionary.